# Can we diagnose and stop spying and tracking activities of android apps?

Tags: applications, 9.0-pie

Recently I read a link

https://telecom.economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/android-apps-caught-tracking-users-even-after-they-say-stop/68010363

Almost all android apps require permissions.

Can we diagnose and stop spying and tracking activities of android apps?

Comment: Yeah, not use the app. But permissions don't automatically mean spying and tracking. Be careful with the permissions you allow, the apps you install, and if in doubt, don't even download it or at least do some googling about the app.

Answer (score 1):

**[Exodus Privacy](https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/)** allows you to scan all non-paid apps availabe at Playstore. **[Appbrain](https://www.appbrain.com/)** lists libraries for both, paid and free apps. **[My app listings](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists)** point out invasive trackers for apps having them (based on the two afore mentioned sites). That way you can check if an app comes with trackers, and avoid it. Using my lists it shouldn't be too hard to find a replacement that doesn't track you – as that fact is pointed out as well.

And don't forget: Avoid Playstore altogether, and use **[F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/)** instead. F-Droid only ships free and open source apps *without any proprietary components* – which means, trackers are left out.